# Is it good practice to have ALL dependencies in a base class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have a WPF application using the MVVM pattern. I'm using Autofac as the DI container. Like other applications similar to mine, I have a ViewModelBase class which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and also resolves dependencies registered in the container:

```
public class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject
{
    protected IErrorHandler _errorHandler;
    protected IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    protected ICustomDialogService _customDialogService;
    protected IUserSettingsRepository _userSettingsRepository;
    protected IReferralRepository _referralRepository;
    protected Notification _notification;
    protected IPrinting _printingService;
    protected ILookupRepository _lookupRepository;
    protected IWorklistRepository _worklistRepository;
    protected IDialogCoordinator _dialogCoordinator;

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        _errorHandler = AppContainer.Resolve<IErrorHandler>();
        _eventAggregator = AppContainer.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        _customDialogService = AppContainer.Resolve<ICustomDialogService>();
        _userSettingsRepository = AppContainer.Resolve<IUserSettingsRepository>();
        _referralRepository = AppContainer.Resolve<IReferralRepository>();
        _notification = AppContainer.Resolve<Notification>();
        _printingService = AppContainer.Resolve<IPrinting>();
        _lookupRepository = AppContainer.Resolve<ILookupRepository>();
        _worklistRepository = AppContainer.Resolve<IWorklistRepository>();
        _dialogCoordinator = AppContainer.Resolve<IDialogCoordinator>();
    }
}
```

The app has approx 20 view models which all require the use of different dependencies - sometimes it will require none. Is it good practice for every view model to have access to these dependencies even if will never use them?

Comment: Your class should have those dependencies it actually needs to work properly. Having said this you usually provide the dependencies via the classconstructor or similar. not from *within* the constructor. So in fact none of your classes should know anything of your DI-container. Instead the contaienr resolves the dependencies in the **calling** context and provides them to the class constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually provide the dependencies via the Class Constructor or similar, not from within the constructor. So in fact none of your classes should know *anything* of your DI-container. Instead the container resolves the dependencies in the *calling* context and provides them to the class constructor. I**t is the callers responsibility to resolve dependencies, not the responsibility of your class. This is the whole point of the Inversion of Control-principle.**

Having said this your dependencies should be resolved similar to this:

```
var errorHandler = AppContainer.Resolve<IErrorHandler>();
var eventAggregator = AppContainer.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
var myModel = new MyModel(errorHandler, eventAggregator);
```

This way `myModel` gets only those dependencies it actually needs for working properly.

To create another model:

```
var customDialogService = AppContainer.Resolve<ICustomDialogService>();
var userSettingsRepository = AppContainer.Resolve<IUserSettingsRepository>();
var myModel = new MyModel2(customDialogService, userSettingsRepository);
```

Comment: What I should have mentioned in my question was that originally I was using constructor injection where each view model only requested the dependencies it needed - but this meant that for view models that were at the bottom of the parent-child viewmodel hierarchy, I would have to pass that dependency down through the chain when instantiating. This got quite messy so my viewmodelbase class which holds my dependencies was my solution.

Comment: @rejy11 Yeah, you should have had mentioned that. Anyway that is how DI works. There´s a single point within your code where the complete dependency-graph is built. All other classes shouldn´t bother for the DI-container at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ViewModelBase` class exhibits the following problems:

- It uses the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). This makes it non-obvious what the class' dependencies are.
- It *exposes* its dependencies to its derivatives, instead of *hiding* them with their behavior from the derivatives, causing the derivatives to violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
- A base class is always *strongly coupled* to its derivatives and so will its behavior, if it has this. This can complicate testing and can in general complicate the derivative.

The use of base classes that include dependencies or *volatile* behavior (i.e. behavior you wish to mock, replace, or intercept in a test suite) is, therefore, considered a bad idea.

Instead of using base classes to group common dependencies, other methods are more effective, such as:

- The use of Decorators or Interceptors to apply cross-cutting concerns
- Using [Facade Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) to hide groups of dependencies *with their behavior*.
- Breaking derivatives up into smaller classes so they need less dependencies.
- Using **Constructor Injection** opposed to the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. As per my comment above, this solution I proposed with all my dependencies in the view model base was only something I tried to see if it would solve my problem. The problem being that when one of my view models sitting right at the bottom of the parent-child hierarchy requires a dependency, it needs to be passed down from the beginning of the chain to the end, resulting in lots of view models simply handing the dependency on to the next view model (when instantiating) - does this make sense?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. It means you are using Method Injection, which you should only use sparingly. Instead, use composition, and build up hierarchies of view models using constructor injection. Each view model can have its own dependencies; those dependencies should not be passed akong to other dependencies (such as other view models)